# Could not find or load main class, after adding CLASSPATH

Tags: java

Hi I'm doing Princeton Algorithms assignment when I ran into the following problem.

Both BruteCollinearPoints.java and input8.txt are in `C:\Users\Jen\Desktop\princeton-algorithms\collinear`.

I have been trying to run 
`java-algs4 BruteCollinearPoints input8.txt` from the aforementioned path to no avail. I kept getting `Error: Could not find or load main class BruteCollinearPoints`.

Below is my classpath:

`CLASSPATH: C:\Users\Jen\algs4\algs4.jar;`

Comment: The main class must be specified with **package** path. Open the algs4.jar with 7zip or such and see wether there is a `/BruteCollinearPoints.class`. In `/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` there should be a line `Main-Class: ...`.

Comment: I opened with notepad. It only shows: `Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: 1.7.0_191 (Oracle Corporation)`

Comment: It is a text file, either the zip tool's internal editor or notepad will do (extracting the file)

Comment: It shows `Manifest-Version: 1.0 Created-By: 1.7.0_191 (Oracle Corporation)`

Comment: It could have lines `Class-Path: ...` and `Main-Class: ...`. Search in the web for a more informative specification. Also I would consider using a `package ...;` statement (subdirectories).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to make sure that your `BruteCollinearPoints` class has `main` method. It could look like the following

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.In;
import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.StdDraw;
import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.StdOut;

public class BruteCollinearPoints {

    // implementation of other methods

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // read the n points from a file
        In in = new In(args[0]);
        int n = in.readInt();
        Point[] points = new Point[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            int x = in.readInt();
            int y = in.readInt();
            points[i] = new Point(x, y);
        }

//         draw the points
        StdDraw.setXscale(0, 32768);
        StdDraw.setYscale(0, 32768);
        StdDraw.setPenColor(StdDraw.RED);
        StdDraw.setPenRadius(0.01);
        for (Point p : points) {
            p.draw();

        }
        StdDraw.show();

        // print and draw the line segments
        BruteCollinearPoints collinear = new BruteCollinearPoints(points);
        for (LineSegment segment : collinear.segments()) {
            StdOut.println(segment);
            segment.draw();
        }
        StdDraw.show();
    }
}
```

For more details please refer assignment's page ([link](http://coursera.cs.princeton.edu/algs4/assignments/collinear.html)).

Also, `CLASSPATH` environment variable should include `C:\Users\Jen\Desktop\princeton-algorithms\collinear`directory as well as `algs4.jar` archive.

`CLASSPATH: C:\Users\Jen\algs4\algs4.jar;C:\Users\Jen\Desktop\princeton-algorithms\collinear`

Execute `javac-algs4 *.java` from `C:\Users\Jen\Desktop\princeton-algorithms\collinear` directory to compile sources to binaries.

Execute `java-algs4 BruteCollinearPoints input8.txt` to run `main` method of `BruteCollinearPoints` class.

Comment: I added `C:\Users\Jen\Desktop\princeton-algorithms` into the CLASSPATH. Compiled my code and ran it successfully!